# Merge all httpHeader to single line

Tags: java, spring

I am using the below snippet to print all headers.

```
import org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders;

@RequestHeader HttpHeaders httpHeaders

httpHeaders.forEach((key,value) ->{
            LOGGER.info("Header Name: "+key+" Header Value: "+value);
});
```

is there a good way to put all to single line?  (StringBuilder I can think of) (My intention is to reduce logging)

Comment: Have you tried the approach with StringBuilder?

Comment: StringBuilder - I am aware with that approach..

Comment: did you face any problems with that solution?

Comment: No.. I was thinking of any cleaner way if available.. Rather than looping and appending

Answer (score 1):

You can use call `StringBuilder`'s `append` in the body of the `forEach`, alternatively use

```
String logString = httpHeaders.entrySet().stream()
    .map(e -> "Header Name: "+e.getKey()+" Header Value: "+e.getValue())
    .collect(Collectors.joining(", ")); //choose any separator here
LOGGER.info(logString);
```

Comment: Thank you.. this looks a good way.. any libraries u are aware like apache common or sping libs?

Comment: how are any APIs related to this?

Comment: libraries I meant

Comment: httpHeaders.toString() also gives the expected result